# Remove selected drop down1 value in drop down2 in select2 jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have 5 drop downs in which if i select one value in drop down 1 and that selected value should not be there in remaining drop downs.

Im using select2 dropdown.
Here i have tried this one
    HTML:
    
      1
      2
      3
      4
      5

```
<select class="select2" id="select2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select class="select2" id="select3">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select class="select2" id="select4">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select class="select2" id="select5">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

jQuery:

$("select").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
    var element = evt.params.data.element;
    var $element = $(element);
    $element.detach();      
    $(this).append($element);
    $('.#merchant_referral_customer_gms_id2').trigger("change");
});
```

This one removing option in self dropdown not in others.

Can  any one please help out.

Comment: Please share HTML also.

Comment: Please check i have edited the code

Comment: Added link of code below

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select_tes").select2();
  
  $('.select_tes').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('.select_tes').find("option[value="+selected+"]").detach();
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class='select_tes'>
  <option value='1'>tes1</option>
  <option value='2'>tes2</option>
  <option value='3'>tes3</option>
</select>

<select class='select_tes'>
  <option value='1'>tes1</option>
  <option value='2'>tes2</option>
  <option value='3'>tes3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In this one option is selecting from both drop downs, but i want option should select in 1 and that selected 1 option should hide in select 2

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not have the required functionality I have tried and made seleted option as disabled in rest of select's please check at following link

```
codepen.io/jainaman23/pen/zzvGpL
```

Comment: This will work with normal dropdowns not with select2 dropdowns